# How to plot a rectangular in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

It is necessary for me that plot a rectangular in MATLAB by contour. But when I plot this, the figure is like square and no rectangular.

In fact the length of X axis and Y axis are true, but figure is not rectangular.

How could I find a  rectangular figure?

Once before I  needed to plot a n eliptical by countour and it was like circle, by setting `axes([xmin xmax ymin ymax])` this problem was solved but know this command do not work.

Here is my code `u0`,`x`,`y` are 3 vectors of length `nx*ny`. and `nx` and `ny` are the number of points in x axis and y axis.

```
figure 
for i=1:ny
    z(i,:)=u0((i-1)*nx+1:i*nx);
    x1(i,:)=x((i-1)*nx+1:i*nx);
    y1(i,:)=y((i-1)*nx+1:i*nx);
end;

cMap = [0.45 0.6 0.65;1 1 1]; % [green;yellow] on rgb-color
colormap(cMap);
axis equal
contourf(x1,y1,z,'LineColor','none')
colorbar
```

Let 's=0:0.1:0.2' and 'x=repmat(s,1,ny)' and 'd=0:0.1:1', 'y=repmat(d,1,nx)'
'u0=x+y'

Comment: Have you tried `axis equal`?

Comment: axis equal does not work too,is there any other thing that I should set?

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: the code you added is not sufficient to reproduce the issue you are asking, can you give and example for `u0,x,y` that makes it happen?

Comment: What about resizing the plot window?

Comment: What about `axis square`? It seems square is really what you want, as an axis is always rectangular.

Comment: How could I resize the plot window?

Comment: Also, `ny` and `nx` are missing.

Comment: When we ask for code, here's what you should do: write your code in a MATLAB script on your computer.  In a clean MATLAB session (with no variables defined) test the script and be sure that the results show what you want us to see.  Then paste that code here.  Simplify where possible: if nx and ny come from some other complicated function, make up some numbers that still show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the size of the vector you are using. Check out this example:

```
x = linspace(0,2,20);
y = linspace(0,1,10);
z = meshgrid(x,y);
contourf(x,y,z,20);
axis equal
```

it gives the following result:
[image]

Now if we check the sizes:

```
>> size(x)

ans =

     1    20

>> size(y)

ans =

     1    10

>> size(z)

ans =

    10    20
```

if the size of x vector is equal to the size of the y vector it gives you a square obviously! in your case first check the size of x1, y1, z just before using the **contourf** an make sure that you are using axis equal after that.

Comment: sorry, but how could I fit axes on rectangular i.e. Y axis be [0 1]

Comment: @Rosa, use the 'axis' command as you used before axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]), and after that use 'axis equal'. if the answer solved the problem please accept the answer. tnx