# How to draw a rectangle using 4 corners on an image in Matlab R2018b?

Tags: matlab, rectangles, drawrectangle

In Matlab, there is `rectangle('Position',[x,y,w,h])` to draw a rectangle object, that `w` and `h` are a width and a height respectively (This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322596/draw-rectangles-on-an-image-in-matlab)). While I try to draw a rectangle on an image using 4 corners: `min_x`, `max_x`, `min_y` and `max_y` that are specified in the following image.

Ex:

> `min_x = 193; max_x = 220; min_y = 168; max_y = 190;`

[image]

I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698455/how-to-plot-a-rectangular-in-matlab) and like that, but they couldn't help me. Is there any way to draw a rectangle with 4 corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```matlab
A = imresize( imread('peppers.png'),0.6);%resizing for better visibility

min_x = 193; max_x = 220; min_y = 168; max_y = 190;

x = min_x;
y = min_y;
w = max_x-min_x;
h = max_y-min_y;

imshow(A)
rectangle('Position',[x,y,w,h],'EdgeColor','r','Linewidth',3);
% Or insert shape to bitmap:
% B = insertShape(A,'rectangle',[x,y,w,h]);
% imshow(B)
```

[image]